# How to create a merge only if the key exists in json using Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a node only if the key exists in my json file. However, it is only able to create some nodes but not all

```
call apoc.load.json($url) yield value 
unwind value as q 
merge (report:Report {filename:q.filename})
ON CREATE SET report.title = q.title,
              report.published_date = q.published_date

// HASHES
with report, value
unwind value.hashes as hashes_obj
with report, value, hashes_obj
where hashes_obj.sha1 is not null
merge (hash_sha1: Hash_sha1 {sha1: hashes_obj.sha1}) // I am able to create this node
merge (report)-[:contains]->(hash_sha1)

// I can't create this node
with report, value, hashes_obj, hash_sha1
where hashes_obj.md5 is not null
merge (hash_md5: Hash_md5 {md5: hashes_obj.md5})
```

Below is my json file

```
{
...
  "hashes": [
    {
      "sha1": "c61b53b85c538dc46254c4f1da7717a29a3b27f3",
      "file_name": "jsunpack.je",
      "is_ssl": false
    },
  ],
...
}

{
...
"hashes": [
    {
      "md5": "a90a329335fa0af64d8394b28e0f86c1",
      "is_ssl": false
    },
    {
      "md5": "07f4b663cc3bcb5899edba9eaf9cf4b5",
      "is_ssl": false
    },
    {
      "md5": "b751323586c5e36d1d644ab42888a100",
      "is_ssl": false
    },
    {
      "md5": "8ad9cb6b948bcf7f9211887e0cf6f02a",
      "file_name": "lsass.exe",
      "is_ssl": false
    },
    {
      "md5": "be0cc8411c066eac246097045b73c282",
      "file_name": "mshtml.dll",
      "is_ssl": false
    }
]
...
}
```

For some reason, I can only create the sha1 node but not the md5 node and I'm not sure why. Please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE hashes_obj.sha1 is not null` test is eliminating all `hashes_obj` maps without the `sha1` property. That means all the maps with the `md5` property are eliminated.

This should work:

```
CALL apoc.load.json($url) YIELD value 
UNWIND value AS q 
MERGE (report:Report {filename:q.filename})
ON CREATE SET report.title = q.title,
              report.published_date = q.published_date

// HASHES
WITH report, value, REDUCE(s = {sha1:[], md5:[]}, x IN value.hashes |
  CASE
    WHEN x.sha1 IS NOT NULL THEN {sha1: s.sha1 + x.sha1, md5: s.md5}
    WHEN x.md5 IS NOT NULL THEN {sha1: s.sha1, md5: s.md5 + x.md5}
    END
  ) AS todo
FOREACH(sha1 IN todo.sha1 |
  MERGE (hash_sha1:Hash_sha1 {sha1: sha1})
  MERGE (report)-[:contains]->(hash_sha1)
)
FOREACH(md5 IN todo.md5 |
  MERGE (hash_md5:Hash_md5 {md5: md5})
)
```